# Getting "Unknown Application ABI" when trying to debug some C code in my Android app

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I'm trying to debug C code in my Android app, following the instruction given [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin), but I when I do "Debug as/Native application" I get `Unknown Application ABI`.

I checked that my NDK path is set correctly as suggested [here](http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/11/android-ndk-eclipse-fixing-unknown.html) and I added the `DUMP_APP_ABI` option to `ndk-build` as suggested [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/19949).

Anybody can help?

```
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Android
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] NDK:
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] WARNING:
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] APP_PLATFORM
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] android-14
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] is
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] larger
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] than
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] android:minSdkVersion
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] 10
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] in
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] ./AndroidManifest.xml
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] 
armeabi
[2013-08-15 11:16:14 - MyProject] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

Comment: Are you using ndk r9?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ndk r9. I found a solution: see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was apparently due to the subliminal message shown between the `Unknown Application ABI` lines. So I added

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
```

to my `Android.mk`, and it works.

Comment: Should be Application.mk...??

Comment: @TonyPark: yes, it should be `Application.mk`

Comment: I have the same kind of error log. I add `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` in `Android.mk`but error persists. Even tried to create a Application.mk file right next to AndroidManifest.xml with `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` content, but it didn't work eather. How to solve this?

Comment: Check that your minSdkVersion in the Manifest file matches the version declared in APP_PLATFORM variable in the Application.mk file. This fix the problem for me.

Comment: doesn't work... still getting:
Unable to detect application ABI's
Unknown Application ABI:

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, "Unknown Application ABI:". And tried all the possible solutions, even want to format my windows. Finally, I find it's TortoiseGit that causes this issue. After remove TortoiseGit, the "debug as native" works pretty well.