# "Unknown Application ABI" error when i debug Android Native Application

Tags: android, android-ndk

i use eclipse(with cdt-master-8.2.0) to debug C++ code in cocos2d-x,but i get some error below, however, when i use Run as-> Android Application or Debug as->Android Application ,it goes well

i strugled for some days and found many people had met similar problem, but i follow many methods , it still didnt work .
  Does anyone know what the cause of this error is  And have solved it? please help me, every word can be appreciate .

my develop environment: window7+ ADT22.0.5-757759 + cdt-master-8.2.0 + android-ndk-r8e + cygwin2.819

```
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Android
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] NDK:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] jni/Android.mk:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Cannot
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] find
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] module
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] with
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] tag
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 'cocos2dx'
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] in
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] import
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] path
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
Android
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] NDK:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Are
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] you
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] sure
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] your
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] NDK_MODULE_PATH
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] variable
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] is
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] properly
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] defined
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] ?
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
Android
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] NDK:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] The
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] following
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] directories
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] were
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] searched:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] 
Android
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] NDK:
[2013-09-13 17:37:04 - HelloCpp] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Unknown Application ABI" when trying to debug some C code in my Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245867/getting-unknown-application-abi-when-trying-to-debug-some-c-code-in-my-android)