# Debugging cocos2d-x 3.1 android project via eclipse on mac

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have setup my environment based on this video steps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LI1IrRp_0w

It helped me to run the app on the device but I cannot debug it. Now I want to be able to debug the test project. By saying debug I mean to placing breakpoints, run application of device and see that it stops on breakpoints. Also I want to see the stacktrace. How I can do this? What eclipse setting I need to configure?

Comment: You don't need to configure anything other then exact `APP_ABI` in your `Application.mk`, In C++ perspective Right click on project and select `Debug As -> Android Native Application`

Comment: @VikasPatidar I have set in `jni/Android.mk` `APP_ABI := armeabi` (there is no `Application.mk`), have run `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` and, as you wrote above, `Debug As -> Android Native Application` but get errors in eclipse. One of them is: `Unknown Application ABI` or `Unable to detect application ABI's`

Comment: Well you can use those flags in both files. Have a look at answer in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245867/getting-unknown-application-abi-when-trying-to-debug-some-c-code-in-my-android

Comment: @VikasPatidar I have looked at that 7 hours ago and commented that error persists :(

Comment: I have used native debugging on eclipse twice or thrice and it's useless. It hangs quite frequently, no matter how good is your Processor and RAM. The error `Unknown Application ABI` may be caused due to many reasons. The best you can do is use `ndk-stack` with `adb logcat` to trace crashes in native code.

Comment: Here is the answer in details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334080/how-to-debug-cocos2d-x-3-native-code-on-android-device